# Postgresql in a Docker Container on Windows: How to persist data to a local windows folder

Tags: postgresql, docker, windows-10

I'm trying to run postgres in a docker container on windows.  I also want keep the data in a windows folder, so I tried this:

```
mkdir c:\pgdata

PS > docker run --name postgres -v c:\pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
d12af76bed7f8078babc0b6d35710dfc02b12d650904ed53ca95bb99984e9b36
```

This appeared to work, but the container is not running and the log tells a different story:

```
2019-07-24 23:19:20.861 UTC [77] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
2019-07-24 23:19:20.861 UTC [77] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
child process exited with exit code 1
```

If I remove the volume option, it starts up fine, but then I don't get my database files persisted where I want them.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: did you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: Nope.  See the answer below and discussion.  Apparently what I want to do is not currrently supported.

Comment: Have u guys already tried with this https://github.com/MatchbookLab/local-persist ?

Answer (score 7):

You did nothing wrong, just have a look for the full log:

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

Data page checksums are disabled.

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 20
selecting default shared_buffers ... 400kB
selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
creating configuration files ... ok
2019-07-25 01:28:18.301 UTC [77] FATAL:  data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" has wrong ownership
2019-07-25 01:28:18.301 UTC [77] HINT:  The server must be started by the user that owns the data directory.
child process exited with exit code 1
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
running bootstrap script ...
```

From above, you can see `fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok` which is executed in [docker-entrypoint.sh](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/ba24350aa02996f75cf5b44eea0af082775cc8ec/11/alpine/docker-entrypoint.sh#L34) to change the ownership from root to postgres, but unfortunately, this just works on linux host not on windows host.

Then, why not work on windows, see [this discussion](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/39#issuecomment-285777521), mainly because current implementation was based on CIFS/Samba which make docker cannot improve it.

So, I guess you have no chance to persist data to windows if you insist to use bind mount.

But, if you not insist, a closer solution maybe use [Named Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-and-manage-volumes) like next:

```
PS C:\> docker volume create my-vol
my-vol
PS C:\> docker run --name postgres -v my-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres
079d4b5b3f73bc0c4c586cdfee3fdefc8a27cdcd409e857de985bead254cd23f
PS C:\> docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
079d4b5b3f73        postgres            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        5432/tcp            postgres
PS C:\> docker volume inspect my-vol
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-07-25T01:43:01Z",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {},
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-vol/_data",
        "Name": "my-vol",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Finally, the data will persist in `/var/lib/docker/volumes/my-vol/_data`, but the limit is this folder is not on windows, it's on hyper-v machine as you may know `docker for windows` use hyper-v to simulate linux kernel.

But it may still meet your requirement, because even you remove current container, next time if you use same volume name(here is my-vol) to mount, the data will still be in the new container, the named volume will not be delete even container deleted, it will be persist in hyper-v virtual machine.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  Though you are correct that it does not fully meet my requirements. I would also like portability. That is, have the data stored outside the vhd. Looks like that's not possible at the moment.

Comment: @user1443098 i guess not, but you may wait some time to see if other folks have good idea, good luck

Comment: What if I have a currently running database and data?

Comment: @osmanraifgunes I'm not sure I catch you. `docker run --name postgres -v c:\pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data -d postgres` will new a database, if you already have a postgresql, why you need do this command? Or you mean "how to migrate data to the new postgresql container from the old postgresql database"? Maybe [this](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/postgresql/import-and-export-a-postgresql-database)?

Comment: I have a database working for development on local machine. I want to containerize it and use the existing content of db. Changes will pushed to source control.

Comment: So, what will you do if you don't consider docker. Say, you have one database working for development on local machine, and you have a production database on another server? I don't see any difference, you still could link to the database in container to alter table etc.

Answer (score 1):

in windows, once you installed docker, you also got `docker-compose.exe` command. so let's use it for your postgres:

step1. create an folder in your host(windows: `D:\workspace\docker_folder\postgres9.5`)

step2. make a `docker-compose.yml` and paste its content as below:

```
version: '3'
services:
  postgres9.5:
    container_name: "postgres9.5"
    image: postgres:9.5
    # notice here, D:\workspace should be written as: /d/workspace
    volumes:
      - /d/workspace/docker_folder/postgres9.5:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    command: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=88888888
```

step3. run `docker-compose up`, then you will see the files in your `D:\workspace\docker_folder`, as below:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how this fulfills my goal.  I want to store the data in a regular Windows folder on the host and be able to access it from the host as well as from insider the container.

Comment: yes, you can surely access this folder both from the host(windows) and the docker.